# IDE под Ubuntu для работы с chromium под андроид?

Tags: android, webview, android-ndk, chromium

Всем привет.
Я программист С++, но в линухе и андроид - чайник. У меня стоит задача модифицировать компонент webview из проекта chromium с целью изменить рендеринг некоторых компонентов. Этот измененный webview затем будет частью поставки нашего продукта.
По сути мне нужно сделать что-то типа web view shell из chromium.

На данный момент я скачал с гит и сбилдил под андроид web view shell из хромиум. Работаю под убунту 14.04. Билдил из командной строки с помощью ninja.

Теперь проблема:

Если бы я работал под виндой, и проект был бы под Visual Studio - все было бы просто. Сбилдил, поставил брейкпоинты где надо, подебажил, нашел участки кода которые отвечают за тот рендеринг который мне надо менять.

А как манипулируют и отлаживают C++ код (и в частности хромиум) под убунту?

В Visual Studio по solution explorer сразу видно какие есть проекты, какие файлы к ним относятся, можно искать по проекту, запускать отладку. Можно как-то так работать с хромиум в убунту, отлаживая apk для андроида? По минимуму хотябы графически видеть структуру проекта, взаимосвязи между файлами, кто к какой либе относится и вот это все как в нормальных IDE.

Для меня сейчас под убунту проект выглядит как 8-гиговая свалка С++ файлов и как с ними что-то делать блокнотом типа sublime3 я не представляю. Не отлаживают же такие проекты в блокноте, ставя брейкпоинты в командной строке!?

Answer (score 0):

У Вас три варианта:

1. Установить *Visual Studio Code*, который помогает только с редактированием кода. Никакой сборки и т.д. он не предусматривает (имеет интеграцию с *GitHub*), но, скорее всего, имеет нужную Вам функций по навигации в проекте. Тут подробнее об [установке](http://myubuntu.ru/programmy/kak-ustanovit-microsoft-visual-studio-code-v-ubuntu).
2. Установить *Visual Studio* в *Wine*. Процесс, скорее всего, геморройный, но *Play On Linux* может упростить Вам задачу. Вы получите требуемую для Вас среду в *Ubuntu* (и, если что-то пойдет не так, уйму опыта).
3. Скачать IDE для *Ubuntu*. Тут очень подробно о различный средах — [тыц](https://habrahabr.ru/post/161217/).

P.S. Но вообще, как показывает практика, самые крутые проекты создаются исключительно в среде *Vim* :D.

Comment: *"как показывает практика, самые крутые проекты создаются исключительно в среде Vim"* -- феерическая чушь.

Comment: @PinkTux, шуток Вы не понимаете :\.